# Boost python, calling function objects with a namespace

Tags: boost-python, python-embedding

I am embedding python in my C++ application, using boost python.

I would like to be able to call a boost python function object, and associate a global name space with that function call. Specifically, the simplified relevant code is:

```
bp::object main = bp::import("__main__");
bp::object main_namespace = main.attr("__dict__");


//Put the function name runPyProg in the main_namespace

bp::object PyProg = exec(
        "import cStringIO\n"
        "import sys\n"
        "sys.stderr = cStringIO.StringIO()\n"
        "def runPyProg(exp):\n"
        "    print exp\n"
        "    exec(exp)\n"
        "    return\n"
        "\n",main_namespace);

//Now call the python function runPyProg with an argument

bp::object py_fn = main.attr("runPyProg");
py_fn(expStr)
```

I know that when I use the boost python exec() function, I can send in the global namespace, as shown above. My question is how do I associate main_namespace with the python function when I call py_fn? My final goal is that local variables from runPyProg will be placed in the main_namespace.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, then it should be as simple as specifying the context in which `exec` will execute.  A function or method can access the namespace in which it is defined via [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals).  Thus, calling `globals()` from within `runPyProg()` will return the Python equivalent of `main_namespace`.  Additionally, [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement) takes two optional arguments:

- The first argument specifies the dictionary that will be used for `globals()`.  If the second argument is omitted, then it is also used for `locals()`.
- The second argument specifies the dictionary that will be used for `locals()`.  Variable changes occurring within `exec` are applied to `locals()`.

Therefore, change:

```python
exec exp
```

to

```python
exec exp in globals()
```

and it should provide the desired behavior, where `exp` can interact with global variables in `main_namespace`.

---

Here is a basic example:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

int main()
{
  Py_Initialize();

  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::object main = python::import("__main__");
  python::object main_namespace = main.attr("__dict__");

  //Put the function name runPyProg in the main_namespace
  python::exec(
    "def runPyProg(exp):\n"
    "    print exp\n"
    "    exec exp in globals()\n"
    "    return\n"
    "\n", main_namespace);

  // Now call the python function runPyProg with an argument
  python::object runPyProg = main.attr("runPyProg");

  // Set x in python and access from C++.
  runPyProg("x = 42");
  std::cout << python::extract<int>(main.attr("x")) << std::endl;

  // Set y from C++ and access within python.
  main.attr("y") = 100;
  runPyProg("print y");

  // Access and modify x in python, then access from C++.
  runPyProg("x += y");
  std::cout << python::extract<int>(main.attr("x")) << std::endl;
}
```

Commented output:

```
x = 42          // set from python
42              // print from C++
                // y set to 100 from C++
print y         // print y from python
100             //
x += y          // access and modify from python
142             // print x from C++
```

Comment: So I've realized that if I have a C++ class PyExpression, and each instance of the class calls boost python exec() to execute its own expression, then all instances are actually using the same global namespace. Is there a way to keep the scope of the namespace to each C++ instance of PyExpression? When I try passing in a boost::python::object that is not initialized to main.attr("__dict__"), the exec() throws an error.

Comment: @user773494:  Namespaces are just dictionaries in Python.  Either update `runPyProg` to accept the namespace in which it will execute the expression (likely the `__dict__` object on the `PyExpression` instance), or use the [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module to extract the desired namespace from the stack.

Comment: Would you be able to point me to a working example of sending in the dict of PyExpression? Having trouble finding anything online. I have essentially exposed the PyExpression class using  `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(PyExpression) { }` I am importing the module and obtaining the namespace as such `bp::object thisExpModule = bp::object( (bp::handle<>(PyImport_ImportModule("PyExpression"))) );` and `bp::object instance_namespace = thisExpModule.attr("__dict__");` When I send in instance_namespace, it works ok as a dictionary namespace, but again all instances of PyExpression modify the same object. Tnx!

Comment: @user773494: Python modules are essentially singletons due to the [import behavior](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement).  If you had a `Foo` class in the `PyExpression` module, then `PyExpression.__dict__` is the module namespace.  On the other hand, with `a, b = PyExpression.Foo(), PyExpression.Foo()`, `a.__dict__` and `b.__dict__` are namespaces specific to each instance.  If you need more help to get a working example, then consider creating a new question with the relevant pieces of code.

Comment: Thanks Tanner, I started a new thread here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569106/boost-python-using-a-namespace-other-than-main-global)